# I cant understand the error

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

> i have written this program with a pointer to function but it gives error `Lvalue required in function main` why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
fun();
main()
{
int fun();
int *ptr();
ptr=fun;   //this line gives error
*ptr();
}
int fun()
{
    printf("amol singh");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this function to do ? As written it makes no sense at all.

Comment: To declare a pointer to a function you need to use parenthesis to group the "pointerness" and the name; otherwise the parenthesis that start the argument list "take precedence". `int (*ptr)(); /*declare ptr as a pointer to a function taking an unspecified number of arguments*/` `int *ptr();/*declare function that returns a pointer to int and takes an unspecified number of arguments*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun() {
    printf("amol singh");
    return 0;
}
main() {
    int (*ptr)();

    ptr=fun;
    (*ptr)();
}
```

Comment: To call a function through a pointer you can use "standard" syntax: `ptr();` would work just as well :-)